# availability of glsl ARB_explicit_uniform_location extension on OSX 10.9

Tags: glsl, osx-mavericks

I would like to know if the glsl extension ARB_explicit_uniform_location is available on OSX 10.9.

According to https://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/opengl/capabilities/index.html, the extension ARB_explicit_attrib_location is available, but it does not state anything about the uniform varient. Can someone verify its absence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is an emphatic **no**, sadly.

`ARB_explicit_uniform_location` was added with OpenGL 4.3 (GLSL 430). This is the reason you do not see that extension listed there, Apple has only implemented up to OpenGL 4.1 so far plus a few extensions from OpenGL 4.2.

You can clearly see this if you run the OpenGL Extensions Viewer (free app that is easy to find in the Apple App Store):

[image: OpenGL Extensions Viewer]

Even though Apple already provides that matrix of supported extensions and implementation limits, I would still highly suggest grabbing this app. It directly links you to the extension specification along with useful information such as when a particular extension went core. On other platforms it is useful for determining what the hardware supports, on OS X you *generally* have pretty common extension support across all hardware (as long as said hardware runs the same version GL context).